# SQL, combining several normalized tables into one result with performance ( Union vs hierarchy)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database which is normalized to store data from several social media sources Blog links, Facebook posts, Youtube videos, Twitter Posts, Linkedin Shares etc.

All have some similarities but also many differences.

Now with the requirement to show these records in one combined view to the user. what would be the most performant way of doing so.

Currently i have a table MEDIA which contains the shared data across records and joins onto other sub tables which contain specific data e.g youtube_media, facebook_meida, twitter_media, blog_media, etc.

Would views be a better way to go?

Comment: I don't think anyone can reasonably answer this question as presented, sorry.. It's quite lacking in detail so it's not easy to imagine what you've constructed. Ultimately it will come down to a lot of factors bespoke to your context. You'd be better off posting your tables, data, asking for solutions to the Actual Problem and then testing those solutions to find one that meets your performance needs

Comment: @ad4m101. . . "better" is highly subjective, particularly when you have provided no objective criteria for determining what "better" means.